# When should AutoLayout Constraints Be Created While Using the UIViewControllerTransitioning Protocol

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uicontainerview

I'm trying to create a [custom container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). I want to use the standard [ViewControllerTransitioning pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html) for animating the addition of child views, but I'm a bit stuck. I'm writing this container view controller completely in code, as the number of child view controllers can vary.

I've already looked at [this tutorial](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/) and it has helped me very much, but I can't figure out this step.

The flow of adding a new child view controller is currently like this:

```
'MyContainerVc'.addNewSubViewController
  Call UIViewController.addChildViewController
  Create transitioning context
  Fetch animator
  Animate
    'Container View'.addSubview
       Create autolayout positioning/height constraints
```

The positioning/height constraints can be created (and are) in the container view, as the container view controller does not need to control them, but the width constraint needs to be created in the container view controller, as the child vcs can specify a `preferredContentSize.width` to my container vc. The container vc will try to respect the child vcs' preferences as much as possible and base the width constraints on it as much as possible.

I'm not sure when the constraint for the width of the subviews can be created. The constraint needs to be enforced before the animation is performed, as the width should be defined before the child view appears. However, I cannot activate it before the child view has been added as a subview and if I activate it after the animation has completed, the width is not defined properly during the animation.

The animator should only use the `transitioningContext` and use the `addSubview` method of the container view, as it should be agnostic to what kind of transition it is animating.

Also, is creating the AutoLayout constraints in `addSubview` the best way to go or should it be done somewhere else, e.g. in `didAddSubview`?

Some advice is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I'm going to create a delegate protocol that specifies a function that tells the container view controller to create the width constraint and I'll call that method in `addSubview` of the container view.